# Почему выводит ошибку если проверить наличие типа в словаре?

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

у меня в словаре находятся типы для проверки на тип присваиваемых данных элементам

почему выводит ошибку если проверить `type(a)#int in dict_1['id']`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Например если проверить тип на наличие в списке ошибку не выводит, а в словаре выводит ошибку [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Значения в словаре не списки: `int` не список, `str` не список. Другие значения - списки. Для них `in` сработает.

Comment: Спасибо Станислав

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте просто использовать равенство: type(a) == allow['id'].

Вы пытаетесь проверить наличие type(a) не в словаре, а в отдельном значении (которое в этом словаре хранится), которое, при этом, не является итерируемым объектом (списком например).

Comment: Спасибо, я так изначально и хотел сделать, но у меня в словарях в качестве значений бывают несколько элементов в списке, например [int, float]. Выше ответ помог мне

Answer (score 0):

1. Значения в словаре не списки: `int` не список, `str` не список. Другие значения - списки. Для них `in` сработает.
2. Не рекомендуется проверять типы в Питоне равенством вида `type(a) == str`. По той же причине плохо писать `type(a) in [int, float]` - принадлежность списку разворачивается в последовательное сравнение типов на равенство.
3. Рекомендуемый способ - [isinstance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance). `isinstance` принимает вторым аргументов тип или кортеж типов. Вот этот код работает так как вам нужно:

> ```
> @>>> allow = {'id': int, 'name': str, 'weight': (int, float), 'price': (int, float)}
> @>>> a = 1
> @>>> isinstance(a, allow['id'])
> True
> @>>> isinstance(a, allow['weight'])
> True
> ```